# %w{ models }.each do |dir| in Rails means?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails guide this came up:

```
%w{ models }.each do |dir|
```

Could someone explain for me what %w{ models } means? Never seen it before. Is it ruby or rails specific.

Thanks

Comment: It must do something different in rails; in pure ruby %w{models} would return ["models"]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`%w{ foo bar baz }` creates an array `["foo", "bar", "baz"]`, it's a shortcut to save typing some quotes and commas. `%{ models }` just creates an array `["models"]`, which does seem slightly superfluous, but is probably just for keeping the style consistent (?).

Comment: It could be that the reader is meant to mentally fill in the names of models. Maybe.

Comment: Yay, my first accepted Ruby answer. The learning is paying off... ;D

Comment: wow, I left that as a comment when no one had answered because I was sure that no one would do such a thing...

Comment: @deceze. maybe the author has several models and each one has to have its own block.

Comment: @fayer Starting with an `.each do` does seem to suggest what @Chuck said: you're supposed to fill in your model names here. It's hard to say without any more context though.

Comment: Just a note that `%w[ a b c ]` is equivalent to `[ "a", "b", "c" ]` where `%[ a b c ]` is actually `" a b c "` since `%[...]` is an alternative way of quoting something, replacing `'...'`.

Answer (score 5):

`%w` allows you to create an array out of a string of words delimited by a space.  here is an example:

```
irb(main):001:0> %w{ foo bar baz }.each { |word| puts word }
foo
bar
baz
=> ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

Here is a decent [reference](http://jimhoskins.com/?p=8).  It is a Ruby-ism, not specific to Rails

Comment: You have the better link though. :D